# Uniswap - cancelled transactions and lost ETH

Tags: uniswap

I started a swap on Uniswap and while it was processing, I started 2 more swaps.

The first swap got stuck for hours so I first tried increasing the gas fee and then eventually, I tried to cancel it.  I also tried to cancel the 2 later swaps.

Once things finally got cleared out, it seems that i have lost the ETH for all three swaps.

Please can someone let me know if (1) I am right, and (2) is there anything I can do about it?!

Many thanks in advance!!

Wallet: 0x92fc173569EFa83cD810C018f497B59854D110dB

Let me know if you need any more info to help!!

Thanks all

Comment: New to UNiSwap, have traded crypt off and on since 2016 though. Same occurred with me, however I did not cancel. There was an issue with gas price, is there anyway to reinstate the transaction with a higher gas price? As to not loose the significant transaction ETH cost? Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You did not lose the Eth you were trying to swap. However, you lost the Eth that you paid as transaction fee.

Transaction fees are not refundable if the transaction reverts (aka is cancelled).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes increasing the slippage from 1% to 3-5% helps make the transaction happen smoothly. Also check on ETH gas prices to see how congested the network is. The more volatile the gas prices are, the more likely the slow transactions likely to fail.